# Can NFC board act as NFC tag?

Tags: nfc, ndef, nfc-p2p, open-nfc

I need to read the text record stored in the NFC board when my Android NFC phone is tapping over it. Now i'm not sure that this is what kind of mode of operation. Can it be like let the NFC board to behave like nfc tag so that i can read from it using NFC phone as reader?

Comment: You definitely need to be more specific with your question. What "NFC board" do you use? Do you already have code running on that board?

Comment: Actually is my partner doing the part for nfc board and I'm doing for the nfc application...He is using adruino pn532..I wonder is it simple exchange of text record also considered as p2p?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you are right. You must make the board like a nfc tag, then use nfc reader(like phone or PN532 board) to read it.

Updated: I think you need Dynamic NFC tag, Like TI's M24SR. It can be store data through I2C, and read with phone.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to send text record to Android then you have to format data as NDEF message as phone only understand ndef formatted data.

Answer (score 0):

Referring the data sheet of Arduino PN532
https://www.electroschematics.com/14474/nfc-rfid-module-pn532/
following are to be noted:
 - Works as a 1443-A card or a virtual card
 - Supports NFC with Android phone
It acts as a Type-A tag and you can read it using the phone

Referring to 
a) PN532 spec, https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/141520.pdf

1. Virtual Card means that the couple PN532+SAM is seen as only one contactless SAM card from the external world.
2. In the Virtual Card mode, the PN532 acts as real contactless card, and all the responses to external requests are handled by the SAM itself; neither the PN532 nor the host controller have to take care of the data exchanges. The PN532 acts just as bridge (analog front-end + antenna) between the PCD and the SAM.

b) https://community.nxp.com/thread/433429

PN532 doesn't include a SAM, but needs to be attached separately

Read of this data is not a P2P operation, but is a Tag read operation